# Pandas Dataframe & NetworkX - NetworkXError: random_state_index is incorrect - linked to my previous question

Tags: pandas, dataframe, networkx

Here is the link to my previous question : [Pandas Dataframe - running through two columns 'Father' and 'Son' to rebuild end-to-end links step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713523/pandas-dataframe-running-through-two-columns-father-and-son-to-rebuild-end)

The fact is that what I want to do with my dataframes in the question above would be much easier going through a networkx MultiDiGraph building.

But I already tried to work with networkx, and could not use it because I always have this error when I try to draw my graphs :

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame({
    'key' : ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K'],
    'father' : ['A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
    'son' : ['B', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
})
df_

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_, source='father', target='son',
                            create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph)
nx.draw(G)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py in _random_state(func, *args, **kwargs)
    395         try:
--> 396             random_state_arg = args[random_state_index]
    397         except TypeError as e:

IndexError: tuple index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

NetworkXError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-4a39fa27cfaf> in <module>
      2                                      edge_attr=True,
      3                                      create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph)
----> 4 nx.draw(G)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py in draw(G, pos, ax, **kwds)
    121         kwds["with_labels"] = "labels" in kwds
    122 
--> 123     draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, ax=ax, **kwds)
    124     ax.set_axis_off()
    125     plt.draw_if_interactive()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py in draw_networkx(G, pos, arrows, with_labels, **kwds)
    331 
    332     if pos is None:
--> 333         pos = nx.drawing.spring_layout(G)  # default to spring layout
    334 
    335     draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, **node_kwds)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decorator.py in fun(*args, **kw)
    229             if not kwsyntax:
    230                 args, kw = fix(args, kw, sig)
--> 231             return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
    232     fun.__name__ = func.__name__
    233     fun.__doc__ = func.__doc__

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py in _random_state(func, *args, **kwargs)
    398             raise nx.NetworkXError("random_state_index must be an integer") from e
    399         except IndexError as e:
--> 400             raise nx.NetworkXError("random_state_index is incorrect") from e
    401 
    402         # Create a numpy.random.RandomState instance

NetworkXError: random_state_index is incorrect
```

I want to extract the graph back to a dataframe that would look like this :

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key' : ['E', 'K'],
    'step_0' : ['A', 'F'],
    'step_1' : ['B', 'G'],
    'step_2' : ['C', 'H'],
    'step_3' : ['D', 'I'],
    'step_4' : ['E', 'J'],
    'step_5' : [np.NaN, 'K']
})
df_2
```

I know I could do it with networkx and it was also advised in comment of the linked question. But I don't understand how to get rid of the nx error.

My environment is last version of `anaconda`, with `Jupyter Notebook` and `Python 3.8.8`, `networkx 2.5`, `Decorator 5.0.6`, `Matplotlib 3.3.4`. I precise it because last versions of `decorator` should have this problem fixed according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920533/networkx-shows-random-state-index-is-incorrect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was I think because of `Decorator 5.0.6`, so I needed to upgrade anaconda to last version where it contains `Decorator 5.1.0`, which doesn't cause this problem anymore.

To complete about the reference to the previous question, I had posted, I had to install `Graphviz` and `Pygraphviz` because it includes better plotting for the graphs. This was also not easy because it's not compatible at first with Anaconda environment, and [the pygraphviz documentation](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html) recommands not to use it with Anaconda.

However, I asked a [question about Graphviz Anaconda installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753534/networkx-issue-need-to-install-graphviz-pygraphviz-anaconda-2021-11-win10x) of those libraries that causes difficulty to a bunch of people. In this question is linked a tutorial for `Graphviz` installation on Anaconda, the question itself shows how to install `Pygraphviz` on Anaconda.